# Weird is_array() behaviour in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have form with several fields I want to store those values in a session variable. Some of those fields should be 0 if the user doesn't fill them in.

A print_r($_POST) after submitting the form shows:

```
[report] => Array
        (
            [a_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                )

            [a_id_card] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                )
            [a_total] =>
```

Yet, after running the following PHP code, it seems that "a_name" and "a_id_card" are not interpreted as arrays. Any ideea why?

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {   
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {             
        if (!is_array($key) && trim($value) == '')  {
            $value = 0; 
            $_SESSION['report'][$key] = $value;        
        } else {
            $_SESSION['report'][$key] = $value;        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On the first "print_r", what's the value of [submit] ?

Comment: "Save form" is the value.

Comment: As I put in my answer: the while loop is with $_POST['report'], and you shoud check if $value is array, not $key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

think you want to write this - is_array($value)

Answer (score 1):

`$key` is the string 'report'. So `is_array($key) == false`. However `$_POST[$key]` or `$value` is an array.

Answer (score 0):

The key is never an array. It is *always* a scalar or string. The value, on the other hand, *can* be an array.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want look only $_POST['report'], and check if 'value' is or not an array (not key):

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {   
    foreach ($_POST['report'] as $key => $value) {             
        if (!is_array($value) && trim($value) == '')  {
            $value = 0; 
            $_SESSION['report'][$key] = $value;        
        } else {
            $_SESSION['report'][$key] = $value;        
        }
    }
}
```